# How to save "NULL" instead of spaces in SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, spaces

It's pretty simple I have some textboxes to fill up and submit to SQL Server, some of them may be blank, so whenever I run the query, I get a bunch of spaces instead of the word `Null` in the database..

My query goes like :

```
 var qry = "INSERT INTO tablename  (Text,Trans, ..)
                              Values ('"TextBox1.text "','" TextBox2.text, ..)";
db.Query(qry);
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: im aware of that, its just a simple collage project so its not a big of a deal

Comment: Using **parameters** would also make it *really easy* to insert `NULL` instead of spaces ..... by assigning `param.Value = DBNull.Value;`  ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better option would be to do something like....

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tablename  (Text,Trans) Values (@Text, @Trans)");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Text" , string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : TextBox1.text);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Trans", string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : TextBox2.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`NULLIF`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO tablename  (Text,Trans, ..)
Values (NULLIF('" + TextBox1.text + "', ''), NULLIF('" + TextBox2.text + "', ''), ..)";
```